# What is the plural form of testing vs test?

Tags: usage

Can "testings" be used to refer to a plural form of "testing"? for example:

> I am waiting to see the results of the genetic **tests**?
>
> I am waiting to see the results of the genetic **testings**?

In regard to "tests" vs "testings" are these two sentences correct? In other words can we use "testings" similar to the usage of "tests"? if not, then what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but is not common in everyday speech.  "Testings" is more used in formal literature, like scientific or engineering journals.

Examples:

> Intercorrelations of all **testings** of all tests were run, in order to determine the relationship of the various tests to each other.
>
> The following tables give the customary summary of the results of the **testings** ... of the quality of the gas supplied by the three Metropolitan Gas Companies.
>
> In statistical academia, the issue of multiplicity is also known as the problem of multiple **testings** or multiple comparisons.

One exception is in certain discussions of Christian thought, in which "testings" refers to the *trials* of Jesus Christ in the New Testament:

> It would be better to speak of **testings** rather than temptations, since the latter word has too often become associated with a yielding approach which was certainly not present in the case of Jesus.

In everyday speech, use *tests*.

> I am awaiting the results of the genetic **tests**.